# Python Selenium: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I have a website where I need to login:

https://gb.clientportal.dunnhumby.com/bkr

I m using `Selenium` to do so. When inspecting the page, the login input field has the following attributes:

```
<input id="userNameInput" name="UserName" type="email" value="" tabindex="1" class="text fullWidth" spellcheck="false" placeholder="someone@example.com" autocomplete="off">
```

I would use the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://gb.clientportal.dunnhumby.com/bkr')
     
username = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#userNameInput")
username.send_keys('test_user')
```

It returns an error: `NoSuchElementException`

I tried to find element by all possible options: `id`, `name` - everything gives an error.

Then I tried the waiting:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://gb.clientportal.dunnhumby.com/bkr')


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
username_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="userNameInput"]')))
```

The error is `TimeoutException: Message: Stacktrace:Backtrace:`
Like even after waiting the element is still not located.

Then I tried to check `iframe`, but there is no `iframe` on that URL.

```
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"iframe"}
```

Any ideas what else I can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a FRAME within which the desired element is wrapped. You first need to switch into the FRAME and then perform action. Refer the below working code:

```
driver.get("https://gb.clientportal.dunnhumby.com/bkr")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "(//frame)[1]")))
username = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#userNameInput")
username.send_keys('test_user')
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Result:**

[image]

Once actions are performed with the FRAME, you can switch back to main content using below code:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Below is the HTML of the FRAME for your reference:

[image]